# AngularJS expression not working within style attribute on IE8

Tags: templates, internet-explorer-8, expression, angularjs

Using an expression like this on the style attribute works on Chrome but doesn't work on IE8

```
style="width:{{progress}}%"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5VDMD/12/  (to test it please type a number in the textbox)

Any workaround for this problem?

Comment: You may want to try using 'ng-style' instead.

Comment: The solution was ng-style="{width: propertyInScope + '%'}" thanks to David https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/Bb6087Gv284

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle with the solution working ok on IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/5VDMD/15/

Comment: This doesn't work even in IE11 btw.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try

```
ng-style="{ width: progress + '%' }"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the best answer.

Comment: I needed single quotes around the css property for Angular 1.5, like so:
 `ng-style="{ 'width' : progress + '%'  }"`

Answer (score 26):

I had to use `ng-attr-style` (though I didn't need to use a function).

```
<div ng-attr-style="width: {{value}}%"></div>
```

Here is a [github discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2186) about this issue.

Answer (score 13):

I made it work that way:

in the controller:

```
$scope.getStyle = function(progress){
    return {
        width: progress + "%"
    }
}
```

in the HTML:

```
<div class="progbar" ng-style="getStyle(progress)"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

For some reason in IE I had to use

```
ng-attr-style="{{METHOD_TO_RETURN_SOME_STYLE()}}"
```

Though mine was in a directive under an ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

if anybody use px instead of %, you have to use this

```
ng-style="{ width: progress + \'px\' }"
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for theOP and further users,when you add some explaination for your intension