# Simple AngularJS Script Works in Chrome but fails in IE11

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a simple AngularJS (v1.3.0-rc.1) page (see below) from the book, Learning AngularJS for .NET Developers (Packt Publishing) page 13, that works in Chrome, but fails to pickup the `<span title="{{color}}" style="background-color:{{color}};">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>` correctly in IE11.  The F12 option in IE shows the style is not being picked up, `<span title="magenta">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>`.  What can the problem be in IE11?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Chapter 1 Example - AngularJS</title>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Introduction</h1>
        <label>My name:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter name" ng-model="name" />
        <br />
        <label>My favorite color:</label>
        <select ng-model="color">
            <option>Please select</option>
            <option>red</option>
            <option>yellow</option>
            <option>magenta</option>
        </select>
        <h3 ng-show="name">Hello! My name is {{name}}.</h3>
        <h3 ng-show="color">My favorite color is <span title="{{color}}" style="background-color:{{color}};">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `style="background-color:{{color}};"` use `ng-style="{'background-color':color}"` IE removes the invalid style value when it finds `{{}}` before even angular has any chance to evaluate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating inline style with angular does not work in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655434/manipulating-inline-style-with-angular-does-not-work-in-ie)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably failing because the browser is attempting to apply styles before AngularJS has gotten ahold of the string and replaced `{{color}}` with whatever value is being set.

Angular offers some angular-specific attributes to handle this discrepancy (`ng-style`, `ng-href`, etc).

Try replacing that span with:

```
<span title="{{color}}" ng-style="{'background-color':color}">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but the we need a start quote, the attribute should be ng-style="{'background-color':color}".  I'm just getting into Angular, looks exciting.

Comment: Thanks, I must've been typing too quickly. ;) I added the missing quote.

Comment: As mentioned in other answers this is a Internet Explorer issue rather than an AngularJS one.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use `ng-attr-style`.

```
<div ng-attr-style="width: {{value}}%"></div>
```

Here is a [github discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2186) about this issue.

Here is a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716993/angularjs-expression-not-working-within-style-attribute-on-ie8/25939651#25939651)  which has more solutions.