# Angular set dynamic style not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to the div height increased by 20px step by step, why below code only works in Chrome but not work in IE?

```
<div ng-repeat="p in percentage">
   <div style="height: {{$index*20+5}}px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-style="height: {{$index*20+5}}px"`

Change it to

```
<div ng-repeat="p in percentage"> <div ng-style="height: {{$index*20+5}}px"></div>
```

Refer to [AngularJS expression not working within style attribute on IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716993/angularjs-expression-not-working-within-style-attribute-on-ie8)